# Calculating word count after stripping HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have encountered a simple yet peculiar problem while calculating the word count of a string that contains HTML. The simple method is to first strip the HTML and then to count the whitespace. The problem I've found is that once you strip away the HTML tags some words are incorrectly concatenated.

See the example below that illustrates the issue using Javascript "textContent" to strip the HTML.

`<p>One</p><p>Two</p><p>Three</p>` becomes `OneTwoThree` and is counted as a single word.

How would you go about counting words (simply)?

```js
var text = document.getElementById("test").textContent;
var words = text.match(/\S+/g).length;
document.getElementById("words").textContent = words;
```

```html
<div class="box" id="test">
<p>One</p><p>Two</p><p>Three</p>
</div>

<div><span id="words">???</span> word(s)</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `innerText` instead to get the all `text` content even with whitespaces.

```js
var textWithoutWhiteSpaces = document.getElementById("test").textContent;
var wordsWithoutWhiteSpaces = textWithoutWhiteSpaces.match(/\S+/g).length;

var textWithWhiteSpaces = document.getElementById("test").innerText;
var wordsWithWhiteSpaces = textWithWhiteSpaces.match(/\S+/g).length;

console.log(wordsWithoutWhiteSpaces)
console.log(wordsWithWhiteSpaces)

document.getElementById("words").textContent = wordsWithWhiteSpaces;
```

```html
<div class="box" id="test">
<p>One</p><p>Two</p><p>Three</p>
</div>

<div><span id="words">???</span> word(s)</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I knew there had to be a simple answer like this, but try for the life of me I couldn't find the answer by Googling or searching in Stackoverflow.

Comment: There's always a catch! I did some investigation into the difference between innerText and textContent and found that innerText needs to be rendered, which is causing performance issues with larger amounts of text.

Comment: Yes, it renders the layout to check if there are hidden elements, if some elements have `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` to not show it, textContent is faster but you need to deal with a lot of edge cases, like the content of `script` and `style` tags, Also the hidden elements will be shown too.

Comment: I benchmarked `innerText` it's ok with small amount of text, it just take few miliseconds, but with large amounts it a bit slow, I test it with 2.5mb of text and it took 200ms, yes it's a bit slow, If the performace matter for you and want to deal with `textContent` you need to deal with edge cases I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for checking Mina. The word counter is running every time there is a change in the editor (which can contain writing that is up to 5,000 words) so it's unfortunately impossible to use. I've decided to continue with the short-coming for now.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could work for you:

1. Replace all tags with spaces, so `<p>One</p><p>Two</p>` would become  `One  Two` .
2. Trim the middle spaces, and make them one space, so our string should just have an extra space on the left and right.
3. Remove that extra space.

```js
let html = "your html";
let tmp = html.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig," ");
tmp = tmp.replace(/\s+/gm, " ");
console.log(tmp.replace(/^\s+|\ +$/gm, ""));

//Now we can count the number of spaces in tmp.
let count = (tmp.match(/ /g) || []).length;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was my first idea and it seems like a good idea. My only reservation is that writing a robust regex to strip HTML seems easy at first but is actually pretty complex (what if you have an angle bracket in your HTML for example). However I think I may need to just go for it because I have the same issue in my Rails code (using the SanitizeHelper).

Comment: I implemented this code and quickly ran into issues, which I think may be greater than the issue I have discovered. This answer doesn't take into account HTML elements such as `&nbsp;` which shouldn't be counted as words. I think you can't get around having to render the HTML (which is bad for performance) or having to write a complex HTML stripper

Comment: @Dagmar Hello, if you could please give some examples where the above code would fail, and I'll try to provide you with a better answer. (Please provide full examples/test cases)

Comment: Ah that's very kind of you aliberro. I could also do it myself, but the point I was making is that stripping HTML is actually a more complex problem than just replacing everything between angle brackets. I have user generated content so there's no end to the possibilities of what the HTML could be. Also, if I was brave enought, there is also another stackoverflow question with loads of answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Comment: @Dagmar This is the best solution from the answers given https://stackoverflow.com/a/47140708/13230268, as mentioned, this is the safest, fastest and easiest to understand, most importantly it can understand stuff like `&nbsp;`, which is important for your case!

Comment: @Dagmar Also this might be helpful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent , check the difference between textContent and innerText

Answer (score 1):

I will add another option to count the number of words among the tags:

```js
const str = '<p><p><p>One<br></p><p>Two</p><p>Three</p><p></p></p><h1>four</h1><b>five</b><H1>123</H1>';

const result = str
    .replace(/(<.*?>)/g, '|')
    .split('|')
    .filter((el) => el !== '').length;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Your answer is pretty similar to the one provided by aliberro except instead of replacing the HTML tags with spaces you are replacing them with the pipe character. I liked your answer though because you included the split.