# Word count regex in HTML

Tags: html, regex, string

This is the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73225259/calculating-word-count-after-stripping-html). But since I'm not using javascript, 'innerText' is not a solution for me and I was wondering if it was possible for regex to combine **/(<.*?>)/g** and **/\S+/g** to get the actual word count without having to make a bunch of string operations.

The language I'm using here is Dart, if a solution I haven't found already exist within it that would work too as an answer. Thanks !

Edit : Someone edited the tags ? This question is not Dart-specific and is about regex, so I'm putting them back as they were.

Edit 2 : The question was closed because it is not "focused", but I do not know how I can make "if it was possible for regex to combine /(<.*?>)/g and /\S+/g" any more focused.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, ***[search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=dart+count+words+in+html++site%3Astackoverflow.com)***; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all text is enclosed in HTML elements, you can use `(?<=>|\s)[^<\s>='"]+?(?=<|\s)`.

With the string `<p>One</p><p>Two Three, Four. Five</p><p>Six</p>` there are six matches.

Note:

1. It uses a lookbehind group, which might not be supported in all browsers.
2. Punctuation at the end of words are grouped with them, e.g. "three," so keep that in mind if you're planning to use the actual words and not just count them.

Comment: That was almost it : it will match `id="chapters"` in `<div id="chapters" role="article">`. Still good for a lot of cases though.

Comment: True, I missed that one. This one shouldn't `(?<=>|\s)[^<\s>='"]+?(?=<|\s)`. Alternatively, you can use this `<[\s\S]*?>` and replace all matches with a space then count the words in the resulting string.

Comment: Magnificent, thank you very much !